# the class file is not on the classpath

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

Intento abrir un antiguo proyecto que realice en eclipse pero me sale este enunciado en todas las clases:

> the class file is not on the classpath.

Quisiera saber como puedo arreglar esto, he buscado en la web por si alguien más le ha sucedió y en la mayoría de ocasiones mencionan que es algo relacionado con el JAR, pero la verdad no entiendo que se debe hacer.

> In Eclipse, go to Window > Preferences > Java > Build Path > Classpath Variables.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muestranos tu pantalla para ver el error

Comment: Ya, eso es lo que me sale en todas las clases del proyecto